# how to sort a list in ascending order LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, reverse

What I have is a data that is being sorted in the descending order but I intend to get it in the ascending orderBy Date.

```
var empList = db.AttendanceLogs.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).ToList();
```

What I tried was `Reverse();`

```
var empList = db.AttendanceLogs.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).Reverse().ToList();
```

But this threw an exception instead.

edited:

arekzyla's answer helped me but I'm stuck at a point where I need to sort two columns both in ascending order like along with DateTime I also want EmpId in ascending order

Comment: Why don't you use this: `var empList = db.AttendanceLogs.OrderBy(x => x.DateTime).ToList();` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Whenever you ask a question that includes an exception, please give details of that exception. Next, look at the method you're calling: `OrderByDescending`. If you just call `OrderBy` instead, that will use an ascending order.

Comment: Yeah simply do `orderBy` instead

Comment: @arekzyla please post an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I'm stuck at a point where I need to sort two columns both in ascending order like along with DateTime I also want EmpId in ascending order*

In SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM AttendanceLogs
ORDER BY EmpID, DateTime  ASC;
```

Using LINQ:

```
 var empList = db.AttendanceLogs.OrderBy(x => x.EmpID).ThenBy(x => x.DateTime).ToList();
```

^The catch here is `ThenBy` which [performs a subsequent ordering of the elements in a sequence in ascending order.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

For **Ascending** order in Linq

var empList = db.AttendanceLogs.OrderBy(x => x.DateTime).ToList();

and **Descending** order in Linq

var empList = db.AttendanceLogs.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using `OrderBy(x => x.DateTime)` instead of using `OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).Reverse()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
var empList = db.AttendanceLogs.OrderBy(x => x.DateTime).ToList();
```

[Enumerable.OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Sorts the elements of a sequence in ascending order according to a key.